# List student where second character of name is 'a' in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

This is my table STUDENT:

```
11  sourav  01-JUN-10
12  kamal   01-JUN-10
13  RAHUL   01-JUN-10
14  SOVAN   01-DEC-10
15  SHAYMAL 01-DEC-10
```

Iam trying to find names, whose second character is an 'A'. I wrote the following SELECT for it:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    student
WHERE 
    REGEXP_LIKE(name,'[a-z]a.*','i');
```

It is not working though. Can someone tell my why?

Comment: Not working? What results do you get?

Answer (score 9):

`LIKE` is better than `REGEXP_LIKE()` for this purpose:

```
where name like '_a%'
```

If you need case insensitivity, you can do:

```
where lower(name) like '_a%'
```

`LIKE` patterns always start matching at the beginning of the string.

As a regular expression, you can do:

```
where regexp_like(name, '^.a')
```

The `^` anchors the regular expression to the beginning of the string.  The `.` matches any single character.

If you want this case-insensitive, you can use:

```
where regexp_like(name, '^.[aA]')
```

Comment: `regexp_like(name, '^.a', 'i')` would also do it.

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways you could solve this including:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE  LOWER( NAME ) LIKE '_a%';
```

or

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE  NAME LIKE '_a%'
OR     NAME LIKE '_A%';
```

or

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE  SUBSTR( LOWER( NAME ), 2, 1 ) = 'a';
```

or

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE  INSTR( LOWER( NAME ), 'a', 2 ) = 2;
```

or

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( NAME, '^.a', 'i' );
```

> It is not working though. Can someone tell my why?

The regular expression `'[a-z]a.*'` is not anchored to the start of the string so it will match and alphabetic character followed by an `a` character anywhere in the string. If you want to find only the second character then you need to start the regular expression with `^` which matches the start-of-the-string.

```
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( NAME, '^[a-z]a', 'i' );
```

You do not need to match the rest of the string so appending `.*` is redundant.

Also, only matching `[a-z]` as the first character is likely to work for most of the names you will encounter that match this pattern but it will not match names with: an accented first character; or a character in an extended character-set first; or with a number or punctuation as the first character. You could make the regular expression more permissive by using `'^.a'` as the regular expression.

Comment: '^.a' this expression means string starting with     first letter as any character  and second character should be a .right

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you want a case insensitive comparison, so you would need something like the following:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENT
WHERE UPPER(NAME) LIKE '_A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENT
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NAME,'^[a-z]a.*','i');
```

**OR**

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENT
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(NAME,2,1)) ='a'
```

Comment: This would not match a name starting with a non-alphabetical character.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

It simple.

Use regexp_like Operator

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENT
WHERE regexp_like(NAME, '^.a');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this.

The simplest one is `where name like '_a%' or name like '_A%'`